# Why video stream every time starts from another time?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I have current code

```
try {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: true
            })
                .then(createLocalStream).catch(function(e) {
                alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
                console.log(e);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(unsupportedBrowserError);
        }

function createLocalStream(stream) {
    localVideoStream = stream;
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    $('#localVideo').on(
        "timeupdate",
        function(event){
            console.log(this.currentTime);
            // onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
        });
}
```

Every time when I'm start streaming, it starts from another time, why and how i can know this time?

Comment: Can you give an example of the times you see…?

Comment: @deceze 
504424.986466
508113.018274
and others, it change's every time it's started.